# Can worklight use IE certificates

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst, keystore

An article tells how to use custom keystore for worklight,
[Custom keystore of worklight](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html). When worklight connect to an HTTPS url, the certificate's issuer should be founded in this keystore or another trusted keystore? if my keystore don't contains an issuer, but I already trust the issuer and saved it into Windows IE's certificate storage, can I use it?

Can we use certificate storage of Windows Internet Explorer as trusted keystore when my worklight development server run on Windows? (I don't want to import any certificates to JRE's keystore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think you can't. WL uses underlying Java application server, e.g. WebSphere or Liberty. Those servers use keystore that comes with JVM. You should import your certificate to either keystore of the JVM used by OS or app server or keystore that is part of the WL project